# In RDFa, difference between property="" & rel="", and resource="" & about=""?

Tags: attributes, semantic-markup, ambiguity, rdfa

I am currently teaching myself RDFa Core 1.1 after successfully learning RDFa Lite rather easily. Straight to the point, I can't understand two things: the difference between `property` and `rel`, and the difference between `resource` and `about`.

Please explain to me in simpler terms than the spec :)

Answer (score 2):

`property` vs. `rel`:

Both attributes indicate a *predicate* of a triple, e.g. `rel="http://purl.org/dc/terms/creator`, which is the predicate `... has as a creator: ...`.

The difference is, from where they take their *object*. Slightly simplified, the rules for `property` are: The object is taken ...

- from a valid `content` attribute or, if this is not present in the tag,
- (if no `datatype` attr is present in the tag:) from a valid `resource` attribute or, if this is not present in the tag,
- (if no `datatype` attr is present in the tag:) from a valid `href` attribute or, if this is not present in the tag,
- (if no `datatype` attr is present in the tag:) from a valid `src` attribute or, if this is not present in the tag,
- from the inner content of the element started by the tag.

Slightly simplified, `rel` differs in two aspects:

- It takes its object only from a `resource` or a `href` or a `src` attribute.
- It takes its object not only from an attribute *of the same tag*, but may also take it from descendant tags. The whole mechanism is called "chaining": "This is the main difference between @property and @rel: the latter induces chaining, whereas the former, usually, does not." [1](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/#h3_s_chaining) Usually, but `property` can induce chaining if used with `typeof` (cf. [2](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/#chaining-with-property-and-typeof)).

`about` vs `resource`:

`about` is the attribute to indicate the *subject* of a triple. The rules for `resource` are more complicated: It may indicate a subject or an object, and chaining plays a role here, too.

IMHO, chaining is the most complicated and confusing part of RDFa (and does not give you more than syntactic sugar). I would avoid chaining. This is possible by avoiding the attributes `rel`, `rev`, `resource` and `typeof`, which brings some further simplification at the same time. Thus, I use only the following attributes:

- `about` for the *subject*
- `property` for the *predicate*
- `content` or `href` or `src` (or the inner content of the element) for the *object*, following the rules outlined above
- `lang` for a language tag for object literals, e.g. `lang="en"`
- `datatype` for a datatype tag for object literals
- `prefix` (but only once in a document), so that I can abbreviate URLs by prefixing, e.g. `property="dc:creator"`
- `vocab` (rarely and at the most once in a document), so that I can abbreviate URLs implicitly, e.g. `property="creator"`.

(And I use the tag `<base href="...">` to indicate the URL base value of the document.)

This is a strict, safe, easy-to-use and easy-to-parse subset of RDFa and allows to express any triple you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend to ignore / avoid using rel and about, they are not really necessary to write RDFa if you follow the rule of thumb that you should not try to be too smart by stuffing as many attributes as possible in a given HTML element. There are around for backward compatibility reasons. The other attributes from 1.1 are worth learning though: content and datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan's advice is in general conformance with [RDF Lite 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/), which does not include `@rel` or `@about` for precisely these reasons.

Another good rule of thumb is to not try to include markup of more than one entity on a given element, which was often an example of specifying an images license.

`@property` and `@rel` are very similar to each others, but served different purposes in RDFa 1.0, but this was confusing, even for experts. (Formerly, `@rel` was used for specifying objects which are other nodes, and `@property` was used for specifying literal values. While there are some remaining differences, but sticking to non-clever markup, you can do everything with `@property` that you could do with `@rel`.

Similarly, `@about` can be avoided to just use `@resource`. The difference is that `@about` sets the current subject and `@resource` the current object, but for child nodes the `parent object` (taken from the parent's `current object` becomes the `current subject`. There were another minor differences concerning the presence of `@typeof`, but if you only use `@resource`, it pretty much does what you want.

To summarize the best practices from RDFa Lite 1.1 you can also check out the [RDFa 1.1 Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/):

- stick to `@vocab`, `@prefix`, `@property`, `@resource`, and `@typeof`
- avoid making more than one statement in a given element

Comment: Thanks for the info but: "While there are some remaining differences..." & "There were another minor differences..."; could you please elaborate?

Comment: Main difference is the behavior of \@property with or without \@rel. If there is no \@rel, \@property can be used for a resource or a literal. In 1.0 \@property only works on a literal. There are also differences if \@about is present and @typeof, mainly to meet developer expectations. Some of the differences are recorded [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/#major-differences-with-rdfa-syntax-1.0). The main advice is to avoid mixing markup on a single element. See [RDFa Lite](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/) for suggested patterns.